# global variables for every http request (not sessions)

Tags: node.js

What is the best practice to have a global variable on each http request?

In PHP you can create a class with static properties which you can call from what ever your scope is in the code..

How can you do the same in nodejs? Sessions is not a solution, because the variable must be reset on every http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the variable must be reset on every http request

Sounds more like a request variable than a global variable. If that is the case, why don't you just add it to the request object.

```
function (req, res) {
    req.myVariable = 'valid for this request';
    ...
    ....
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could avoid polluting req too much by creating a property of req called req.globals or something then adding the "global variables" to that.

Comment: @AlexMA. Right. I read the "a global variable" in the first line. Sure. Best practices need to be followed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't criticizing your answer, but simply adding an optional twist on it.  I put global variables in quotes because the author isn't really talking about true global variables which would persist across requests.

Comment: but how can you then call the `req.globals` from a given scope?